# What's the best way to declare a DataFrame that updates itself inside a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am reading multiple CSV files and averaging them. Due to memory constraints, I can read only one at a time, so I have a routine for reading them on a loop that looks like this:

```py
first_iteration = True
for path in paths:
    print(f'Reading path {path}')
    sub = pd.read_csv(path)
    if first_iteration:
        first_iteration=False
        pred = sub['meter_reading']/len(paths)
    else:
        pred += sub['meter_reading']/len(paths)
```

I was wondering if there's good practices for such situation. The term `sub['meter_reading']/len(submission_paths)` is repeated and I was wondering if it is possible to simplify the previous loop to something like this:

```py
for path in paths:
    print(f'Reading path {path}')
    sub = pd.read_csv(path)
    pred += sub['meter_reading']/len(paths)
```

The problem is that I can't declare `pred` before the loop. I'd like it to be `pred =` in the first iteration and `+=` in the rest.

As someone commented, I also tried initializing an empty DataFrame, however, that does not work as well.

Comment: set `pred = 0` before loop. And then you can use `+=` in all iterations.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The title mentions _"a list"_ yet `pred` is not a list.

Comment: *"The problem is that I can't declare pred before the loop."* Why not?

Comment: if `pred` is a `DataFrame` then you may have to assign empty `DataFrame` to `pred` before loop. It may need also columns.

Comment: It depends on that that `pred` is.  If a number, then `pred=0` is fine.  If a list, then start with `[]`, and list append (not `+`).  But an action that only takes place the first time is not 'redundant'.  In the overall scheme of things the `if` test is fast.

Comment: pred is a pandas Series that I am reading from a csv file. pred=0 definitely is not a solution. Neither pred=[]. I am going to try an empty dataframe, however, the dimension will be updated when I read the first CSV file.